# Pressing back button does not suspend/terminate application

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've created an app with secondary tiles. The tiles leads to Page2.xaml of the application. So when the user clicks it, the app opens on that page (Page2).

Ive added the following at the end of OnLaunch in app.xaml.cs:

```
foreach (string id in ListOfId)
   if (id == e.TileId)
   {
      rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
   }
```

Pressing back button (hardwarebutton) leads back to Page1, the first page of the application. Thats the wanted behaviour. The problem is, if I then press back on the Page1 it only flips the page... seems to reload it?

If I start the application by its default tile that leads to Page1, and then press back button the app suspends (expected).

Can I trigger suspension of the app in code? I can override hardware back button and might solve my problem that way

Comment: Does it mean that when you open the App from Tile, you are unable to exit/suspend it - it always reloads the Page1? Are you handling somewhere BackButton behaviour?

Comment: @Romasz When the application is launched by a secondary tile, it goes to Page2. Pressing back button leads to Page1 as it should. THEN pressing back at Page1 should suspend the application, where it only seems to "reload" Page1.

Comment: Is there a chance that you can share an example project with the issue? It looks like: 1. The BackStack of the Frame still holds the Page1 and every time you call it Navigates back. or 2. e.Handeled = true of BackButtonPressed event then it cancels the default behaviour.

Comment: @Romasz how can I clear the backstack of the frame?

Comment: When you finish Navigation - for example in `OnNavigatedTo`: first get the *Frame* - `Frame mainFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;` then `BackStack` is just *IList* - you can remove for example like this: `mainFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);`.